# Apple/Macos /usr/bin/env (used in shebang) ignores/resets the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable

Tags: bash, macos, environment-variables, sh, shebang

I often use the `env` utility in the shebang to call `python2` because the location of `python2` is not always the same accross systems :

```
/usr/local/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

Therefore, here is my the shebang line I use :

`#!/usr/bin/env python2`

My pb. is that the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable gets ignored or reset by the `env` utility on Macos :

I have the following line in my `.profile` :

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib
export DUMMY=$HOME/local/lib
```

Let `testENV.sh` the following shell script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

test $(uname -s) = Linux  && echo "=> LD_LIBRARY_PATH   = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
test $(uname -s) = Darwin && echo "=> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"

echo "=> DUMMY = $DUMMY"
```

If I run `./testENV.sh` on LINUX, the result is :

```
=> LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /users/EtuX/0123456789/local/lib
=> DUMMY = /users/EtuX/0123456789/local/lib
```

If I run `./testENV.sh` on Macos, the result is :

```
=> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH =
=> DUMMY = /Users/xyztxyzt/local/lib
```

If I print the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable using `echo` from outside the script (at the bash prompt), it shows :

`/Users/xyztxyzt/local/lib`

INFO : My `.profile` is a symbolic link to `.bash_profile`

EDIT 2 : On Macos, the `env` utility seems to be the "guilty" one :

```
$ which env
/usr/bin/env
$ env bash testENV.sh
=> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH =
=> DUMMY = /Users/xyztxyzt/local/lib
$ bash testENV.sh
=> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = /Users/xyztxyzt/local/lib
=> DUMMY = /Users/xyztxyzt/local/lib
```

EDIT 3 : Replaced `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`

EDIT 4 : Updated the `testENV.sh` shell script.

EDIT 5 : Updated the `testENV.sh` shell script with the `DUMMY` variable.

Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: `.profile` is loaded by the login shell, probably not the newly created environment of the subprocess

Comment: Does it work if you export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the shell you are using to run the script?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @CristiFati You are right on the name of this variable, but this pb. occurs with any exported variable on Macos

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak If I echo the variable from outside the script, it show the content of the variable, this means the variable is already exported

Comment: Does _bash_ use _.profile_? It has its own set of files (at least on some *OS*es): _.bashrc_ and _.bash\_profile_. You should `echo` something from _.profile_ and see whether it gets printed out when executing your script.

Comment: @CristiFati My `.profile` is a symbolic link to `.bash_profile`

Comment: Test with a different environment variable (PATH for example).  I suspect Mac does some funny things with DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.  No; I don't have clear explanation.  It seems, roughly, that a given shell can set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, but it is reset to empty when a new shell is started.  (I can reproduce the problem using your script on my Mac.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I guess you are right. Updating the question with another variable